# Getting application version from within application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, versioning

Is there a simple way of obtaining the application version information from the resource file at runtime?

Effectively what I'd like to do is be able to have a "Version X.Y.Z" displayed at runtime without having a separate variable somewhere that I'd have to keep in sync with my ProductVersion and FileVersion.

To clarify: yes this is a standard C++ Windows project. I am aware of the [GetFileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method but it seems silly to have to open the binary from within the version in memory just to query the version information - I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here :-)

Answer (score 7):

If the OS is Windows, use the `GetFileVersionInfo` and `VerQueryValue` functions.

Comment: As per my edit - that would involve having to open the file, I'd like a more elegant solution if it exists.

Comment: The version information is available for every binary file. In contrast, the image in memory is made up of several files. The PE image that is loaded in memory does not have a file version. It only includes the linker version and OS version.

Comment: The version information is part of the PE resources and resides in the `.rsrc` section, which unless marked as discardable is resident in memory. Version resources are localisable and thus it is advisable to use the specialised version-info Windows API to access them.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe that there's an easier way (than opening the file and using GetFileVersionInfo and VerQueryValue). I use the following code, in case it's helpful:

```
static CString GetProductVersion()
{
    CString strResult;

    char szModPath[ MAX_PATH ];
    szModPath[ 0 ] = '\0';
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, szModPath, sizeof(szModPath) );
    DWORD dwHandle;
    DWORD dwSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize( szModPath, &dwHandle );

    if( dwSize > 0 )
    {
        BYTE* pbBuf = static_cast<BYTE*>( alloca( dwSize ) );
        if( GetFileVersionInfo( szModPath, dwHandle, dwSize, pbBuf ) )
        {
            UINT uiSize;
            BYTE* lpb;
            if( VerQueryValue( pbBuf,
                               "\\VarFileInfo\\Translation",
                               (void**)&lpb,
                               &uiSize ) )
            {
                WORD* lpw = (WORD*)lpb;
                CString strQuery;
                strQuery.Format( "\\StringFileInfo\\%04x%04x\\ProductVersion", lpw[ 0 ], lpw[ 1 ] );
                if( VerQueryValue( pbBuf,
                                   const_cast<LPSTR>( (LPCSTR)strQuery ),
                                   (void**)&lpb,
                                   &uiSize ) && uiSize > 0 )
                {
                    strResult = (LPCSTR)lpb;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return strResult;
}
```

David

Comment: C style casts?! Who are you and where is David? ;-) Thanks for the snippet

Comment: Yes, valid criticisms. Apologies also for the use of a static global function and a CString. In my weak defence, this is from a hobby project only!

Answer (score 4):

The only officially supported approach is to use `GetFileVersionInfo()` and `VerQueryValue()`.  However, as you have noticed, `GetFileVersionInfo()` requires you to pass in the filename of the executable.  [There is a reason for this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061226-06/?p=28603).  Although it is simple to obtain the running process's filename using `GetModuleFileName()`, it is not the most efficient option, especially if the executable is running from a remote share, and it is not even guaranteed to be accurate if the executable has been modified on the HDD after the process has started running.

You can access the version info of the process that is already running in memory, by calling `FindResource()` to locate the process's `RT_VERSION` resource, then use `LoadResource()` and `LockResource()` to obtain a pointer to its data.  It is tempting to then pass that pointer as the `pBlock` parameter of `VerQueryValue()`, but beware because doing so [can crash your code](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061226-06/?p=28603)!  If you access the `RT_VERSION` resource directly then you are better off not using `VerQueryValue()` at all.  The [format of the `RT_VERSION` resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647001.aspx) is documented, so you can parse the raw data manually, it is not very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

As already said there is no easy way.

You can find [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.language/2006-01/msg00151.html) a great working example (ATL free).

Comment: Link no longer works