# How to find the application version for both windows and linux from within application

Tags: c++, linux, winapi

I am familiar with `GetFileVersionInfo` and `VerQueryValue` for windows. I am looking for a solution which is platform independent .I am using boost so preferably something in boost that can be used for both the platforms.
I have read a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12405248/4686445) which was windows focused.

Comment: Do you want to get the running executable's _own_ version, or some other executable's version? Because if you need its own version, you could just add a `#define` for that.

Comment: @Thomas Yes I need the running executable's version. Can you highlight what would go into #define?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. **You** decide on the version information to use, and set it, at compile-time. There is no reason to forget this information, only to try to recover it at run time again. Just use compile-time constants, wherever you would have called the hypothetical retrieval function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're trying to get the executable's own version, why not just add a `#define`? For example:

**`version.h`**

```
// include guards etc.
#define MY_PROGRAM_VERSION "1.2.3"
```

---

To pull the version from your `CMakeLists.txt` rather than hardcoding, try this:

**`version.h.template`**

```
// include guards etc.
#define MY_PROGRAM_VERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION}"
```

**`CMakeLists.txt`**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0) # Use higher if you need, lower won't work.

project(test VERSION 1.2.3) # The one and only place where you define your version!

configure_file(version.h.template version.h)
```

I assume you have something like that `project(...)` line already, to configure the version. Among others, it sets a CMake variable named `PROJECT_VERSION`.

The [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html) call takes the template, fills in variables that CMake knows about, and writes the output to `version.h`, which you can `#include` normally. When either the version or the template changes, CMake will regenerate the file.

Comment: So the version number is set in the CMAKE for the project. How can I extract it from there during run-time?